# Proving $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb D$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $\mathbb D$ is the set of real numbers such that $a\in \mathbb D$ iff $(a,0)$ is constructible. I have proven $\mathbb D$ is a field of constructible numbers and now want to prove $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb D$.

So to prove something is a subset of the other I believe we just need to prove they are the same size and an element from one goes into the other. So if $(a,0) \in \mathbb D$ where $a$ is a real number then am I able to assume that $a\in \mathbb Q$ since there's a chance $a$ could be irrational?

Comment: No. What yoiu should prove is that $a\in\mathbb{Q}\implies(a,0)$ is constructible.

Comment: So did you show that $\mathbb D$ is a field?  Can you show that $1 \in \mathbb D$?

Comment: I proved that $\mathbb D$ is a field, closed with respect to taking square roots of positive numbers, so I would assume yes, $1\in \mathbb D$.

Comment: "I believe we just need to prove they are the same size".  The word "size" is ambiguous and can mean different things be I can not think of any common meaning where subsets need to be the same size as their supersets.  You just to to show that for an rational $q$ then $(q,0)$ is contructable.

Comment: Does $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb D$ mean sub***set*** or sub***field***.  If you've proven that $\mathbb D$ is a field, it suffices to prove $(1,0)$ is constructable.  As $1$ generates all of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: If you proved that $\mathbb{D}$ is a field that contains $1$, you are done. As a field contains sums, differnces, multiples and quotients.

Comment: To prove $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb D$, you prove that if $b \in \mathbb Q$ then it has to follow that $b \in \mathbb D$.  You don't care anything in general about $a \in \mathbb D$ which may or may not be rational.  It doesnt matter if there are $a \in \mathbb D$ where $a \not \in \mathbb Q$.  YOu seem to be confusing this with proving $\mathbb Q$ *EQUALS* $\mathbb D$ (which isn't true).  Hence your strange comment about "equal size".  Subsets are absolutely *not* required to be equal size.  If the sets are finite and the subset is proper they can NOT be equal size.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{D}$ implies that for any element $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ we can find an element $(0, a) \in \mathbb{D}$. Providing a construction method of $a$ would show this.

Write $a = \frac{p}{q}$. Mark points $P = (0, p)$, $Q = (q, 0)$ and unit point $U = (1, 0)$. Draw line $PQ$. Draw a line $L$ intersecting $U$ parallel to $PQ$. By argument of similar triangles, the intersection point of $L$ and $OP$ is at $(0, a)$. All of these operations can be done with a ruler and compass.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> So to prove something is a subset of the other I believe we just need to prove they are the same size and an element from one goes into the other.

No. That is to prove two sets are *equal*.

To prove a set $A\subset B$ you must prove that any arbitrary element (and thus all elements) of $A$ is an element of $B$.  You absolutely do *not* have to show that an arbitrary element of $B$ is an element of $A$.  If $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ that will certainly be false.

You absolutely do not have to prove they are the same size.  It is possible for two subsets to be the same "size" but as the superset $B$ will have elements that the proper subset $A$ will *not* have, we should certainly not expect equal size.

So to prove $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb D$, you have to prove that if $q \in \mathbb Q$ then $q \in \mathbb D$.  Or in other words that all rational numbers $q$ that $(q,0)$ is contructible.

You claimed in the comments that you proved $D$ is a field.  If so you are done.  If $1$ is in a field (which it must be as it is the multiplicative identity) then all the sums and quotients that can be generated by $1$ are in the field.  That is precisely $\mathbb Q$.

It is a property of $\mathbb Q$ that $\mathbb Q$ is the "smallest" ordered field, and consequentially, $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of all ordered fields.